# Java linebreaks/newlines in CSV text email attachment breaks the complete attachment

Tags: java, csv, jakarta-mail

I'm mailing a CSV text file as an attachemt with Java which I generate in my program. If I add the string containing data (header and values), the attachment seems fine except for the fact that everything is on one line (i actually forgot about the linebreaks).

```
MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
attachPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(s3_string.getBytes(), "text/csv")));
multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
```

However, when I add linebreaks in the form of "\n" or "\r\n" in the string the whole attachment is messed up, I get stuff like
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; etc etc"

and whatnot in my original mail.

Is there a way to add linebreaks to the CSV so that it becomes a valid CSV attachment?

Thanks in advance,

Hello world!

Comment: I don't know this API at all, but you could try using the raw encoding used in emails, which I believe is the same as `%`-encoding but with `=` instead of `%`. In other words, try replacing `\n` with `=0A`. (And if this does work then don't forget to make sure you escape all the other special characters as well.)

Comment: Thanks David, I tried that but the result is the same as with using \n or \r\n

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

I was reading the file from s3 into a LinkedList with Strings but that already seemed like an inefficient way to go (although more efficient as writing the file to tmp and attaching it). I fixed it by:

```
                    MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                    try {
                        ByteArrayDataSource byte_array_data_source = new ByteArrayDataSource(s3.returnS3Object(this.bucketName, raw_s3_file_location).getObjectContent(),"text/csv");
                        attachPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(byte_array_data_source));
                        attachPart.setFileName(raw_s3_file_location.substring(raw_s3_file_location.indexOf("/")+1));

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
```